# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to make a name generator that uses preset syllables accessed from three different arrays.

```
#include "main.hpp"

Namegen::Namegen() {
}

const char *Namegen::getFirst() {
    const char *name;
    int rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
    const char *firstSyllable = start[rNum];
    rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
    const char *secondSyllable = mid[rNum];
    rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
    const char *lastSyllable = end[rNum];

    name = firstSyllable + *secondSyllable + *lastSyllable;

    return name;
}
```

There are a total of 6 syllables in each array, so I have the min set to 0, and the max to 5. Six numbers in total. Yet, for some reason, it looks like it's generating an 8 somewhere? I'm not entirely sure what the exception is talking about, but hopefully someone else does. This is the exception (even though it's in the title already):

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.
```

This is my Namegen.hpp file (linked through the main.hpp file):

```
#pragma once

class Namegen {
public:
    const char *start[6] = { "Ba", "Ce", "Ti", "Mo", "Lu", "Dy" };
    const char *mid[6] = { "ma", "te", "di", "so", "ku", "ly" };
    const char *end[6] = { "ban", "can", "dan", "fan", "gan", "han" };

    Namegen();
    TCODRandom *rng;
    const char *getFirst();
};
```

Why is it throwing this exception, and how do I fix it?

I got it to the point that I can successfully concatenate the values, using the following code:

```
std::string Namegen::getName() {
    int r = rng->getInt(0, 2);
    std::string firstSyll = fSyll[r];
    r = rng->getInt(0, 2);
    std::string midSyll = mSyll[r];
    r = rng->getInt(0, 2);
    std::string lastSyll = lSyll[r];

    std::string name = std::string(firstSyll) + std::string(midSyll) + std::string(lastSyll);

    return name;
}
```

However, it now throws this exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF978AD9E7A (ucrtbased.dll) in AotDK.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Comment: You cannot assign value to `const` variables. You can only initialize them (I'm kinda surprised it compiled). Since you don't initialize `name`, it's some random rubbish pointer. You then try to write to that location, which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: What did you expect `name = firstSyllable + *secondSyllable + *lastSyllable;` to do?

Comment: You can probably consider using `std::string` and a STL container such as `std::vector`. Also, look into how you are concatenating the portion of names.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, OP doesn't try to write to the location pointed to, by `name`. He assigns said memory location, without dereferencing it.

Comment: I'm coming over to C++ from C#, so please forgive my ignorance. I wanted it to concatenate the values and create a name, but it looks like I was horrendously misjudging the usage of the + operator when referencing this sort of thing.

Comment: @JacobMcNamara Then, you should learn C++ from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Learning C++ by guessing is **not** the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

`name = firstSyllable + *secondSyllable + *lastSyllable;` is nowhere *near* a concatenation. (The compiler compiles it as it thinks you're doing some pointer arithmetic on `firstSyllable`.) The behaviour is actually undefined as you are assigning something that isn't `nullptr` or the address of an object to `name`.

Ditch all the `char*` stuff, and use `std::string` instead. Then `+` *will* act as a concatenation as it's an overloaded operator in the string class.

Your data would then take the form

```
std::vector<std::string> start = { "Ba", "Ce", "Ti", "Mo", "Lu", "Dy" };
```

which demonstrates the power of the C++ standard library. You need to `#include <string>` and `#include <vector>` to bring in that functionality.

Comment: I'm getting the following: namespace "std" has no member "string".

Comment: @JacobMcNamara `#include <string>`?

Comment: @JacobMcNamara: See next comment up and the amendments to the answer. By the way, C++ is not a shallow learning curve! Really you need a good book. Stroustrup is my favourite, by far. And I'd set three months aside and read K & R first; completing all the example exercises.

Comment: I've got that much working now, however it comes down to it that the library I'm using to make this game doesn't use std::string it turns out. I won't be able to use std::string for this purpose without going through and recoding the library. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can do all the string manipulation using std::string, then call the c_str() method if you need (read-only) access to the character buffer.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to use c_str in this context. Do you want me to c_str() the firstSyllable, mid...etc. or the std::string name?

Comment: @JacobMcNamara: That depends on what the function that you're attempting to call that expects a `const char*` is. Really now is the time for you to down tools and start reading.

Comment: @JacobMcNamara : To add to Bathsehba's answer, initialize the `start`, `mid` and `end` part of the member-initializer list instead of the way you do it in the question. If you are not aware of this, then a good book will certainly let you in on that info.

Comment: @VishaalShankar Looks like I need a book, then. I do most of my learning on Lynda.com right now, is that a good source?

Comment: @JacobMcNamara. No it isn't. Apologies in advance for the dogma, but read K & R first (and do the exercises), then Stroustrup.

Comment: Wait, I just realized I could overload the function giving me the error so that there's an overload that doesn't interfere with the rest of the library. I don't know why I didn't see this before, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Okay, I got it to compile with this code: `#include "main.hpp"

Namegen::Namegen() {
}

std::string Namegen::getFirst() {
 std::string name;
 int rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
 std::string firstSyllable = start[rNum];
 rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
 std::string secondSyllable = mid[rNum];
 rNum = rng->getInt(0, 5);
 std::string lastSyllable = end[rNum];

 name = firstSyllable + secondSyllable + lastSyllable;

 return name;
}` but it's still giving me that 0x00000000000008 exception. Edit: Wow, that looks horrendous in a comment. Should I update my question so it's easier to read?

Comment: I like your answers in general Bathsheba because they explain the problem and suggest a solution very concisely.

Comment: @JacobMcNamara check you're _actually_ compiling and run the _actual_ new program.

Comment: @YSC That's very kind of you to say so!

Comment: @Bathsheba I got it to the point that it's throwing an exception in a different spot now, if that makes any difference. Check my question above for the details (I will update it here in a sec)

Comment: Nevermind, I know what the issue is now. Part of the code in this library is using strcat_s on the value of the name, but when I overloaded the function that uses this value so I could use std::string, I made it that calling on actor->name returned NULL. Nice one, me. Maybe I should hang this one up and settle for a Markov chain...